# How to get signature parameters from a transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, parity, signature, raw-transaction

In my application I have to manually verify certain transaction signatures on the ethereum blockchain. Atm I am running geth and parity nodes and query transaction information via the rpc interface but it seems to be missing the ecdsa sig params.

From what I see, both geth and parity do not seem to expose signature parameters via the rpc interface like bitcoind does (it exposes the input and output scripts with `get_rawtransaction`). Is there an easy way to access them or do both geth and parity strip signatures in their local blockchain caches once signatures were verified for some reason? I am wondering because even [ecp](https://github.com/ethereum/ecp/blob/master/importer.go#L28) only seems to parse the raw transactions from blocks into `txhash`,`rcpt`,`from`,`amount`,`price`,`gaslimit`,`payload` (=data), `blockid` missing the signature params (or are they hidden in the payload field?).

What would be an option to get complete raw transaction information as if I'd just signed it with `web3.eth.sign()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the transaction object returned by `eth_getTransaction` to my geth instance does include the ECDSA parameters:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionByHash","params": ["0x47ced780ecca7c273243dded62c6a240f3ba4332ab067345909a304d7294cfda"],"id":1}' localhost:8545

{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "result": {
    "blockHash": "0x7126318b5736f655049fcb7c3f6ef02d0986a5553cb1b1fbc0ca188543b1e60a",
    "blockNumber": "0x339d04",
    "from": "0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8",
    "gas": "0x15f90",
    "gasPrice": "0x4a817c800",
    "hash": "0x47ced780ecca7c273243dded62c6a240f3ba4332ab067345909a304d7294cfda",
    "input": "0x",
    "nonce": "0x15dcf8",
    "to": "0xf34a762291e2578b79646cbf296abf4f5a242b3d",
    "transactionIndex": "0x0",
    "value": "0x16978c7c04171dc",
    "v": "0x26",
    "r": "0xe448b291661c63d8add23a8be2eb726e92ace5c100e902ee75a6396f8df8d221",
    "s": "0x197fb2e88dc2d4e8f606faf6abdb8012d21b024939756ceaf2d39b4bef619fa4"
  }
}
```

Note the `v`, `r`, and `s` parameters: these are what you need to verify the signature. I'm not sure why these aren't in the official RPC spec, but they are available if you need them

Comment: Same on parity.